# If I move into a home I own but allow existing renters to remain can I start the clock on partially avoiding capital gains?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, rental-property

I have had the same great renters for a number of years. I do realize that I can not avoid capital gains on the home appreciation accrued during that time.

But what if I were to move in as my primary residence yet continue to rent to them? It's a very big home so it actually feels like a bit of a waste for being "just me". But then would I be able to start the minimum-2-year-as-primary-residence clock for avoiding capital gains that would occur starting from the time I moved in?  Or would it be only a partial result - determined by the proportion of the home that I personally occupy?

Comment: Are you going to reduce their rent since they will not have full use of the entire house? If you don't reduce the rent you may have taxable income on the rental portion of the house.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep how would reducing rent affect its tax treatment?

Answer (score 3):

The capital gains subject to exclusion are not per calendar days you live in the property, since no-one can actually attribute your gain to a specific date. Instead, it is being prorated.

For example, you lived in the property 2 years and rented it out for 8 years before moving into it yourself. So 20% of your capital gain can be excluded under Sec. 121, and 80% cannot. [See 26 USC Sec. 121(b)(5)(B)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/121) and [the relevant IRS guidance](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p523#en_US_2021_publink100077085).

To your question, the period where it was **your** primary residence is what matters. You would still have depreciation for the rental portion, and depreciation recapture is not excluded under Sec. 121 at all.

Comment: I don't see this answer supported in the [IRS descriptions](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc701) of [Sec. 121](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p523). There is no mention of proration. Rather, up to $250k of gain (for an individual) is excluded provided you've been the owner-occupant for at least *2 of the last 5 years*. In your example, 8 years of non-residence followed by 2 years of residence would qualify for the full $250k exclusion.

Comment: @nanoman IRS publications are not a legal authority. Law is. See 26 USC Sec 121(b)(5)(B) - Gain allocated to periods of nonqualified use: https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/121. The IRS descriptions of Sec. 121 does cover the nonqualified use periods calculations here: https://www.irs.gov/publications/p523#en_US_2021_publink100077085

Comment: Thanks, I see what I missed in Pub. 523. Interestingly, if the non-residence period more than 2 years before the sale involves renting out "*only a portion*" of the home (anything less than 100%), then [the exclusion isn't affected](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p523#en_US_2021_publink100077086). But indeed, this isn't the situation in the question because OP has been renting out the *entire* home before moving in. An interesting loophole? If OP had locked one closet and forbidden the tenants from using it, then 2 years after moving in, they wouldn't need to prorate in this way?

Comment: Also, it might be good to clarify that (at least as I read it) the $250k exclusion itself is never prorated -- rather, the *gain that can be reduced* by the exclusion is limited to the "residence portion" (20% in your example). If the gain is large enough (very valuable house), then the proration won't really matter, because once the residence portion of the gain exceeds $250k, you'll get the value of the full exclusion anyway, right?

Comment: @nanoman locking the closet is not enough, he has to use it as his primary residence. So people who buy a house and rent every room to others leaving one to themselves can live with roommates who pay their mortgage and also get the tax benefit. A lot of folks are doing that.

Comment: @nanoman and yes, the gain is prorated. "It" referred to the "capital gains" in the previous sentence, sorry if it is confusing.

Comment: You have to reside in the home for a 2-year period. What I'm saying is if *before* that period, you were renting out everything but a closet, then the entire gain would be eligible for exclusion per the letter of the section I [linked](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p523#en_US_2021_publink100077086) ("Exceptions: Space within the living area, Space formerly used for business or rental").

Comment: @nanoman, no, you misunderstood. This discusses a partial renting or business use of your primary home, for example renting out a bedroom or using a room for a home office. It doesn't describe a case where you leave a nominal part inaccessible to renters in order to claim that it remains your primary residence.

Answer (score 1):

"The Section 121 ... exclusion allows you to exclude from taxable income $250k ($500k if married filing jointly) of capital gains if you’ve lived in the property as an owner-occupant for the previous two of five years."

"The good news is that you will get to apply the Section 121 exclusion to the portion of the home you owner occupy, but you will unable to apply it to the portion of the home that is rented."
https://www.biggerpockets.com/blog/2016-02-21-tax-implications-house-hacking

Comment: That is not entirely correct. The proration of gain per living area is only needed if areas are explicitly separate. For example, if you live in one half of a duplex and rent out the other - you can only exclude half the gain. But if you rent out a single room in your otherwise undivided dwelling - then you do not need to prorate the gain.